# Force date range picker to always display in a chronological order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have vuetify date range picker

[image]

Right now it displays

[image]

I would like to **force** to always display in a lesser date order first for my model.

Ex. 5/1/2022 - 5/14/2022

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed prop to sort/format the dates, and bind the result to the text field's `value`:

```html
                         
<v-text-field :value="datesText" readonly />
<v-date-picker v-model="dates" range />
```

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    dates: [/* date strings */],
  }),
  computed: {
       
    datesText() {
      const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US')
      return this.dates
        .sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b))   // sort chronologically
        .map(d => dateFormatter.format(new Date(d))) // format date in en-US locale
        .join(' - ')
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ZEroYor)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by sorting an `v-model` input value.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    dates: [],
  }),
  computed: {
    dateRangeText () {
      return this.dates.sort().join(', ')
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        cols="12"
        sm="6"
      >
        <v-date-picker
          v-model="dates"
          range
        ></v-date-picker>
      </v-col>
      <v-col
        cols="12"
        sm="6"
      >
        <v-text-field
          v-model="dateRangeText"
          label="Date range"
          prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
          readonly
        ></v-text-field>
        model: {{ dates }}
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```